# Avoid StackOverflowError when a call to a non existing URL is made

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have a web application with Spring MVC running on top of a Tomcat 7.0 server.

The application runs fine, but whenever I try to call a URL that is not configured, I see lots of error and a `StackOverflowError` exception. A sample of my log:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet BatchUI threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.getManager(ContainerBase.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2905)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2310)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:592)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:592)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:592)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
```

My application initializer looks like this:

```
private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "BatchUI";
private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING = "/";

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    //Load application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(SpringContextConfiguration.class);
    rootContext.setDisplayName("User Interface");

    //Context loader listener 
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    //Dispatcher servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = 
            servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1); 
    dispatcher.addMapping(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING);
}
```

After around 10-15 seconds, an Internal Server Error is returned to the browser, but my log gets full of traces like the one I posted.

So, is there a way to avoid these errors?, or perhaps a better way to handle them?.

I was thinking on adding a Filter and checking the request to validate if the URL exists, if not, then redirect to an error page or something.

Thanks you so much for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modified your web.xml file. Using following code.

```
<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the redirecting to another page, I still want to know if I can avoid having lots of StackOverflowError exceptions.

Comment: take a look on this project https://bitbucket.org/hebertsouza87/exemplorest/src
I think you are not using the spring mvc in the best way. this project is a base for restful api, but it realy uses the spring mvc